# Using wildcard argument with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, wildcard, arcgis-10.6

I have a python code I'm running in ArcGIS 10.6 that replaces the data source path of all layers in the mxd with a new path. I'm trying to use a wildcard for the current workspace path as many layers in our template mxd have different data source paths.

The part of code in question is this line:

mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(r"*", r"P:\JOBS\2018\18-9992\Drawings\GIS")

The r"*" doesn't seem to work as a wildcard.

Here is the full code:

```
# Importing necessary modules
import arcpy, os

# Setting path to mxd and Data Frame
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "UTM_12")[0]

#List layers and replace current path with new path
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
    mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(r"*", r"P:\JOBS\2018\18-9992\Drawings\GIS")

#Delete any layers with broken links (no datasource)
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
    if lyr.isBroken:
        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)

# Saving the mxd
mxd.save()
```

Comment: I think you can use lyr.workspacePath in the first parameter instead of the wildcard.

Answer (score 2):

Using `lyr.workspacePath` worked as long as I used if `lyr.isFeatureLayer` to avoid groups layers and rasters.

Answer (score 0):

Set the layer's workspace path directly instead of using `findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths`:

```
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
    if lyr.isFeatureLayer:
        lyr.workspacePath = r"P:\JOBS\2018\18-9992\Drawings\GIS"
```